# Does anybody know how to boot a PC Desktop CQ 1010LA from a pen drive?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb, bios

This PC, released in 2011, originally came with Windows 7 Starter 32 bits and now is updated to Windows 10 Home. Its motherboard is Foxcom 2ACA with Legacy BIOS, AMI 7.07 from 2011. BIOS interface is relatively simple. It lacks Secure Boot.

I`ve attempted many times to boot from different pen drives in order to install Windows 10 with Windows Media Creation Tool, with Rufus for UEFI and with Rufus for Legacy. Windows detected them as external storage  devices, were verified as bootables by using Emutest and Movalive and  were tried at least in 3 different USB ports.

Clearly the PC recognizes the pen drives in the Boot Order, particularly those for UEFI since they are automatically shown as selected in UEFI Boot Sources with a little white arrow indicating priority. After confirming either of the pendrives for UEFI the Windows logo shows up and then the screen turns light blue shutting down within 2 minutes. No text whatsoever is to be seen.

When the PC is turned on again keeping either of the pen drives connected, the same behaviour repeats itself. You need to disconnect the pen drives-with the PC off- to get Windows to boot in a normal way. Undoubtedly both pen drives for UEFI interact with  Windows -keeping it from booting- maintaining their priority, but at the moment of truth they cannot boot. The pen drive for Legacy does not work at all. It does not affect the booting process because Windows  boots without delay. I've tried other sofware programs like Unetbootin to no avail.

I have read scores of pages on the topic and watched all the HP and Compaq's available videos and tried everything they advise, unsuccessfully. I want to replace  the old HDD vith  a SSD and perform a  clean installation of Windows 10.
Until now all the technical advice I've been given  has been fruitless and a bit of a grope in the dark. EasyBCD  and Plop Boot Manager failed too.

Someone,somewhere must know exactly how this particular PC operates.

Comment: What happens if you use the proper windows media creation tool rather than Rufus?

Comment: Both the Windows Tool and Rufus for UEFI respond in the same way.

Comment: I've read somewhere that certain BIOS updates can cause some issues. Maybe in this case it took away the BIOS ability to boot from another devices. Who knows?
I tried to boost from a pen drive for the first time in January 2020 with Windows 7, just before the PC update to Windows 10.  Therefore I am not in a position to know if this particular model ever had the ability to boost from store devices or even its optical drive. By the way, the PC currently  doesn't boost from it either.
I wonder if there have ever been computers that lack the ability to boost other than the hard drive.